# Слетают права на сервере

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, apache, веб-сервер

```
Виртуальный Сервер: 5.7.26-0 ubuntu 0.16.04.1.
Apache/2.4.18.
PHP: 7.0.33-0 ubuntu0.16.04.5
```

Более месяца работал стабильно. Буквально на днях начала появляться проблема: у сайта (cmf modx) отнимаются права доступа, и ни один плагин не работает, соответственно, любая информация на сайте перестает отображаться (как понимаю, доступ для чтения php файлов движка пропадает).

После

```
chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/sites/
```

работа восстанавливается.
(sites - директория, где лежит папка с сайтом непосредственно).

Слабо разбираюсь в серверном окружении, поэтому не могу понять в чем дело. 
ТП сервера поверхностно проверила логи, сообщили, что никаких ошибок нет.

**UPD: stat на некоторые файлы**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: видимо полтергейст никому не встречавшийся ранее, и даже нет идей на что обратить внимание. здорово...

Comment: Дайте хотя бы примерные конфиги httpd демона для сайта.

Comment: Покажите с какими правами оказываются файлы в `/var/www/sites/`

Comment: 1. `stat файл-со-слетевшими-правами` в студию, до момента "возвращения" ему прав. 2. покажите все кронтабы. в общем виде, глянуть можно так: `sudo crontab -l -uapache` - это крон задачи для апача. Покажите все, к которым есть доступ. 3. А нет ли случайно скриптиков, которые "защищают" файлы путем выставления "правильных" прав? Либо в самой CMS, либо какой-нибудь скрипт "защити свой сайт от хакеров"?

Comment: @Total Pusher таких файлов получается много, а именно - все исполняемые файл движка. Но какие конкретно, не знаю. Попробую завтра на произвольных файлах попробовать "stat". Сегодня проблема не повторилась (бывало и такое), но завтра думаю снова все слетит. Дольше двух суток стабильно не работало, проблема плавающая. Задачи по крону только те что я задавал (на запуск php файлов с парсером сторонних сайтов, но они отрабатывают ночью). В CMS ничего такого нет, ни защитных скриптов на серваке. По крайней мере о тех что мне известно.

Comment: Еще напишите, это какой вид хостинга - VDS или шаред. Если шаред, есть ли контейнеризация (на основе докера, либо хостер сам придумал свой контейнер)

Comment: @TotalPusher это виртуальный сервер, настроенный по их же рецепту LAMP. Сегодня проблема снова проявила себя, стабильно утром. Данные через stat на некоторые файлы до и после команды "chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/sites/" идентичны (скрины добавил в тело вопроса)

Answer (score 0):

Одним решением будет добавить пользователя, с которым вы работаете с файлами, в группу `www-data`:

```
gpasswd -a www-data username
```

Таким образом Apache, выполняющийся с правами пользователя `www-data`, будет иметь доступ к тем же файлам, к которым имеет доступ тот самый пользователь, во владения к которому переходят файлы.

Подсмотреть какой именно `username` нужно использовать можно после того как сбросятся права. В вашем вопросе не указано до каких значений сбрасываются права.

Например, права могут сбрасываться если вы загружаете файлы по FTP - это вы делаете явно с правами пользователя, отличного от `www-data`. Достаточно добавить `www-data` в группу того пользователя, с которым появляются файлы, чтобы решить проблему доступа.

[Более подробно об этой схеме на примере nginx читайте здесь.](https://www.alexeykopytko.com/2010/nginx-gpasswd-www-data/)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не понял, о каком обновлении идет речь?.. Я захожу из под рут пользователя просто напросто. Получается, командой gpasswd -a www-data root, я дам apache все права root? Извините, если вопрос бессмысленный, плохо знаю серверную среду.

Comment: Причем интересный момент - права сбрасываются в какой то определенный временной промежуток обычно, как правило утром, в 7-8 часов. Потом сутки проблем нет. На след.день смотришь - опять не работает, делаешь  chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/sites/ , все снова функционирует, до следующего дня..

Comment: @Amsterdam был у меня хостер, у которого проблемы начинались именно в указанный промежуток времени. Поставил на сервер "скрипт - шпион", который в лог записал и уличил  в пинании сервера тех. поддержки хостера.  По предъявлению  доказательств предложили с ними расстаться, что я и сделал.

Comment: @Amsterdam дополнил ответ

Comment: На счет прав на файлы - дополнил вопрос скринами. Вроде, они остаются прежними в обычном понимании прав доступа к файлу, но при этом прав на запись у системы не остается, появляются только после команды chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/sites/

Comment: А покажите права на файлы _до_ команды chown.

Comment: @sanmai они идентичны, о том и речь..

Comment: @sanmai скрины сверху отражают права и "до" и "после"

Comment: Какие из них до, а какие - после? Подпишите. Кстати, права везде одинаковые на всех скринах.

Comment: @sanmai права не меняются, мы об этом и говорим. Именно эти скрины сделаны после выполнения команды, но и До нее они выглядели бы точно так же.